# Shortcut method for n columns compared against the same constant?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I can't find an answer one way or the other for this. Pretty simple question with very little detail.

Is there a better way to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename tn
WHERE tn.col1 = 1
      AND tn.col2 = 1
      AND tn.col3 = 1
      AND tn.col4 = 1
      ...
      AND tn.coln = 1
```

Where multiple columns all have to be compared the same way to a single constant?

Comment: If you were using SQL 2012, you could probably play around with the new `CONCAT` feature, and do something like `WHERE REPLACE(CONCAT(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6), '1', '') = ''`, but that may not even perform as well as the above query, and probably isn't as grokable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the best way to do this.As per my understanding there is no other bettwr way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

About the only thing I can think of (and it would only be useful in certain circumstances) is to add a persisted calculated field to the table itself that uses logic as follows below.  I wouldn't recommend this approach for a highly transactional table and really would only even consider it if this is a filter used in many places and quite often. What is gained is a single value you can filter on and index so SELECT will be optimized.

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] 
   ADD SAMEVALUE AS (CASE WHEN col1 = col2 AND col1 = col3 
       AND col1 = col4 AND .. col1 = coln THEN col1 ELSE NULL) PERSISTED
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "better" here means "less typing"? If so, you can speed things up by using Intellisense or a third-party tool that does the same thing, or if you have a large number of columns then use your favourite scripting language (Perl, Python, PowerShell, whatever) to generate the `WHERE` clause for you. You can even use SQL itself:

```
select 'tn.' + quotename(name) + ' = 1 and '
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('MyTable')
and name like 'col%'
```

But please remember that you spend much more time reading code than writing it, so the most important thing is that the meaning of the query should be as easily understood as possible, and your current query is already very clear.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for something along the lines of `(col1,col2,...,coln) = 1` but it doesn't look like anything like that is possible. I can solve my specific issue in a different way easily, I was just wondering if there was any faster (typing) way to do it.